# Javascript: Import local files (csv or txt)

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

For my current job, I am working on modifying some program's (VarSeq) report modules, which are written in javascript. I need to import local file from a fixed location(stored as .csv) to javascript. However, when the program generates the report from javascript, it does not publish the output on the server, but as local html file (file:/// extension)

I did lots of research, and found several methods to read csv files, but they were either inefficient or not plausible.

I found **XHR, jQuery csv module**, but it seems that they require me to have server that supports transfer protocols.

**FileReader() API** was the last thing I looked at, but it requires users to select file, which I want to avoid if possible.

Does anyone know if it is possible to automatically load local csv file (fixed location) in javascript other than three methods I described above?

Ideally I want something like

function(path_to_csv_in_local){

read the file

store data

}

Thanks everyone

Comment: You can not read files directly off the computer. That is how it works. You might have good intentions, but there are tons of people that do not.